# Automatically organize downloads from Whatsapp Web with Python

Tags: python, web, whatsapp

Is it possible to make a program in Python in which the program automatically organize downloads from Whatsapp Web with Python?

By default when downloading an image (or file) from WhatsApp Web it remains in the folder "C:\Users\Name_User\Downloads" for windows users.

The purpose of the program is to dynamically change the default directory and to store each download according to the number (or name) of the contact from which the file comes.

Is this thing possible on python?

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing you can manipulate and list any files with standard os module(copy,delete,move files,create directories etc.).Also a third party module called watchdog can monitor directory or even files changes.

Comment: By default the images (or files) when downloaded by Whatsaap Web, only include time and date information. And with this it would not be enough to organize the downloads according to the number (or name) of each contact with only the standard operating system module.

Or at least not automatically, without having to modify the name of each download beforehand.